# How to identify records with no link in separate table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have people in my database in the PERSON table, and each person is supposed to have at least two criteria assigned to them in the PERSON_CRITERIA table (the CRITERIA table stores the actual criterion). I want to show all the records that have less than two criteria assigned to them (including no criteria at all). I tried this but it doesn't work as I am hoping:

```
SELECT PERSON.Last_Name, PERSON.First_Name FROM PERSON_CRITERIA 
INNER JOIN PERSON 
ON PERSON_CRITERIA.Person_ID=PERSON.Person_ID
HAVING COUNT (* ) < 2
```

This works without that "HAVING" line. It returns a PERSON record for every instance of criteria assigned to them in PERSON_CRITERIA. I want to only show the ones with less then two assigned to them, including none. With the HAVING statement included, it returns this error:

```
Column 'PERSON.Last_Name' is invalid in the select list because 
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I don't think this would work anyways because the JOIN statement probably eliminates all of the records with no criteria. Help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an aggregate, columns in the SELECT cause must be in a GROUP BY or aggregated (COUNT here)

```
SELECT PERSON.Last_Name, PERSON.First_Name FROM PERSON_CRITERIA 
INNER JOIN PERSON 
ON PERSON_CRITERIA.Person_ID=PERSON.Person_ID

GROUP BY PERSON.Last_Name, PERSON.First_Name -- missing this

HAVING COUNT (* ) < 2
```

To find where there are *no* rows in PERSON_CRITERIA (edited to fix table order)

```
SELECT 
    PERSON.Last_Name, PERSON.First_Name 
FROM 
    PERSON
    LEFT JOIN 
    PERSON_CRITERIA ON PERSON_CRITERIA.Person_ID=PERSON.Person_ID
GROUP BY 
    PERSON.Last_Name, PERSON.First_Name
HAVING 
    COUNT (PERSON_CRITERIA.Person_ID) < 2
```

Comment: shouldn't you use left outer join. If there is no criteria for a person, that won't be shown with your query right?

Comment: it might be, but to answer him you should use the second part of your answer because the first part don't show person without criteria.

Comment: @aF.: I thought I'd also explain why the aggregate is broken too... because that is OP's reported error whether the query is logically correct or not... Do you disagree with that?

Comment: first you explained why it didn't work. Afterwords you editted because you didn't saw/notice the full question? :P You can leave it that way ^^

Comment: Same as my comment on the other one, this seems like it should work, but it returns nothing. And I know have some with no criteria.

Comment: @gbn: Should be a **right join** to person (or swap person_criteria and person around). Either way, person should be on the inner side of the join.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: Oops. Thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 4):

[`INNER JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014.aspx) means that there has to be a record in both sides of the join..

You need to use the [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx). (*and you also need to use `GROUP BY` in order to be able to use the [`HAVING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) with an aggregate*)

```
SELECT 
    PERSON.Last_Name, 
    PERSON.First_Name 
FROM 
    PERSON 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PERSON_CRITERIA ON PERSON_CRITERIA.Person_ID=PERSON.Person_ID
GROUP BY 
    PERSON.Person_ID,
    PERSON.Last_Name, 
    PERSON.First_Name 
HAVING COUNT (PERSON_CRITERIA.Person_ID) < 2
```

Comment: The trick is the left outer join, which returns records from the person table, even when no corresponding record exists in the criteria table.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but nothing is returned, and I know I have records with no criteria.

Comment: @digitaloday, do you have unique last and first names ? To be sure add `PERSON.Person_ID` to the `GROUP BY` columns..

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli: Should be a right join to person (or swap person_criteria and person around). Either way, person should be on the inner side of the join.

Comment: @digitaloday, ok my fault.. the `PERSON` should be the first table (*as it is used as the `LEFT` in the join*). Updated answer..

Comment: @Mark, yes i just noticed and updated answer.. thanks for spotting too :)